# Avoiding a fixed point theorem.

Tags: differential-geometry, fixed-point-theorems

Serge Lang, in his "Fundamentals of Differential Geometry", states in Lemma 5.4:

> **Lemma 5.4:**
> Let $U$ be open in $\mathbf{E}$, and let $f: U \rightarrow \mathbf{E}$ be of class $C^1$.
> Assume that $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = I$.
> Let $r > 0$ and assume that $\bar{B}_r(0) \subset U$.
> Let $0 < s < 1$, and assume that
> $$
>   |f'(z) - f'(x)| \leq s
> $$
> for all $x, z \in \bar{B}_r(0)$.
> If $y \in \mathbf{E}$ and $|y| \leq (1 - s)r$,
> then there exists a unique $x \in \bar{B}_r(0)$ such that $f(x) = y$.

Here, $\mathbf{E}$ is a Banach space, but if you regard it as a finite dimensional normed space, it is fine.

The demonstration sets
$g_y(x) = x - f(x) + y$, and uses the **Shrinking Lemma**
to get a fixed point.
That is, a point such that $x = g_y(x) = x - f(x) + y$.

The **Shrinking Lemma** itself, is a bit dynamic:
you start at a point and iterates $f$ so it converges to the fixed point.
I would like to see this kind dynamic in the context of **Lemma 5.4**.

So, in order to compare proofs, my question is:

> Can you show me a proof that does not use the **Shrinking Lemma**?

Of course, I do not expect you to simply embed the **shrinking lemma** inside your proof. Ideally, I would like to see some dynamical construction. Sorry for my subjective requirements. :-)

Comment: Tou want to solve an equation $f(x)=y$. What about the Newton method ? This is an iterative method (like Piacrd fixed piint) but converges more quickly.